# How to SELECT * from an wcf application, database hosted in appharbor

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, appharbor

this is my first time playing with WCF in visual studio (2015), and I am running into some problems. 
I have my database hosted in appharbor. I managed to insert new items into the database with:

```
    public Test Insert (Test TestTable)
    {
        SqlConnection conGet = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connectionString, conGet);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testID", testTable.testID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testName", testTable.testName);

        conGet.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (testID, testName) VALUES (@testID, @testName)";
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        conGet.Close();
        return testTable;
    }
```

PROBLEM: when I tried to select from it:

```
    public Test GetData(Test test)
    {
        SqlConnection conPut = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", conPut);
        conPut.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.Depth>0)
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                test.testID = (int)rd["testID"];
                test.testName = rd["testName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        conPut.Close();
        return test;
    }
```

rd (SqlDataReader) is not reading anything and just returns a null value, even though the test table has rows in it.

Please give me some pointers? I have tried several methods online, and no luck.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that test for Depth. The Sql DataProvider doesn't support that property. It is always zero

Source: MSDN [SqlDataReader.Depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.depth(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The outermost table has a depth of zero. The .NET Framework Data
>   Provider for SQL Server does not support nesting and always returns
>   zero.

If you want to test the condition of no rows then use the property [HasRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.HasRows)
{
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        test.testID = (int)rd["testID"];
        test.testName = rd["testName"].ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. i tried it, and now it highlights test.testID = (int)rd["testID"] and says "An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in CMMS-WCF.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Specified cast is not valid." The table was created via type "char", so i tried to do test.testID = (char)rd["testID"] and that didn't work too... any suggestions?

Comment: When you cast to (char) the error is the same? Are you sure that every row retrieved by the query has values in the column involved? What is the size of the column testID? We cannot directly cast something that is not of the correct type or if it is null. A column of type char is a string for NET. Look at this page on MSDN about [SQL vs NET type mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes... i get the same error. The columns has value in them. Here's how the table was created:

Comment: Sorry but I can't see this info. This is important to know how to correctly extract the value of the rd["fieldName"]. The collection of fields is typed as object in NET and we need to apply the correct conversion

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry, looks like it didn't go through. I changed the property types to string like you suggested, and it worked! Thanks :D. I just have one last question. I had to put everything into a list, in order to grab all of the data. however i need to return an object. i tried to cast it, but it didn't work... is there another way to do it? thank you!